# Will all the stat history and settings (goals etc.) be transferred after moving to Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'll try to be very specific:
There is a website with a GA script in old format ga.js, and Universal Analytics GTM tag with the same tracking ID but another property number (Let's say UA-1234567-1 and 1234567-2). So the GA account provides stats tracked by Universal Analytics and old standard Analytics.

The conversions and goals are customized only in old standard Analytics. Universal Analytics doesn't show them

I'm going to delete the code of old Analytics, and put its property to installed Universal Analytics code instead of current property (replace 1234567-2 with 1234567-1).

The question is will all the stat history and settings (goals etc.) be transferred to the that property, or I need to do something else to move it to that property?

Thanks

Comment: The title and the body are asking different things, can you align that a bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem.

[On the server side your accounts are running Universal Analytics in any case:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/#important-considerations)

> 100% of Google Analytics properties have been transferred to
>   Universal Analytics, and all new properties will be Universal
>   Analytics properties.

Migrating to the new code is not different from the migrations all of us had to do when Universal Analytics was rolled out, except that you do not have to click a "migrate" button. Ga.js is officially deprecated and only supported as a courtesy (the German version of the help page still says that ga.js will be supported for at least two years, although it seems this information is not on the english page).

A bigger problem might be that Universal Analytics uses cookies differently (a single cookie with a user id instead of five cookies with precomputed tracking information), but the new tracking code has a compatibility layer so returning visitors will still be recognized as such etc.

The only things that will fail are things that are no longer supported by analytics.js (custom vars, which have been succeeded by custom dimensions, and all hacks that depend on reading GA cookies). But the settings for your property will not change.